# NSString integerValue returns a number in hex

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
NSString *x = @"12345";
NSInteger nsint = [x integerValue];  
NSLog(@"%x", nsint);
```

Prints 3039. intValue has the same result. Any idea how I can get the actual decimal value out of that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  NSLog(@"%d", nsint);
```

`%x` means hex format. (See http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265 for all format specifiers.)

Comment: Oops, someone had told me %x was integer and %d was double. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSLog(@"%d", nsint);
```

%x prints hex; %d prints decimal.